# Line number info not available error while debugging Ant project in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ant, breakpoints, bytecode

I am working with a fairly old Java Ant project, which I have imported into IntelliJ, it previously having been developed using Eclipse.  The project consists of a small number of servlets.  I am trying to debug from IntelliJ.  IntelliJ can connect to remote Tomcat on port 8000, but when I try to add a breakpoint I get the following dreaded error:

> Line numbers info is not available in class com.package.blah.SomeClass

Following advice on SO and elsewhere, I modified my Ant build script to the following:

```
<target name="compile" depends="web-skeleton">
    <ant dir="${deployment-wizard.dir}" target="uberjar"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" srcdir="${src.dir}"
        destdir="${build.dir}/WEB-INF/classes" classpathref="project.class.path"/>
</target>
```

I added the `debug` and `debuglevel` lines to the above target which calls `javac`.  Also, I have tried running `javap -v SomeClass.class`, where I see things like the following:

```
  line 94: 418
  line 97: 433
  line 98: 443
LocalVariableTable:
  Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
    343      22    13 decrypted   Ljava/lang/String;
    370      11    13     e   Ljava/lang/Exception;
    244     189     7 keyParam   Ljava/lang/String;
    255     178     8 userParam   Ljava/lang/String;
    266     167     9 environmentParam   Ljava/lang/String;
```

I don't know if this means that the bytecode contains line numbers, but it certainly appears this way.

I have also tried cleaning and rebuilding from scratch and doing an invalidate caches/restart from IntelliJ.

I hope that someone can offer some help here.  As a last resort, I can try porting it to a Maven project, but I would prefer to avoid this unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Have you tried to clean/rebuild your project after adding debug options?

Comment: Yes, I went way beyond this, even doing invalidate caches in IntelliJ, cleaning, restarting.  I gave up...I spent the afternoon porting it to a Maven project, which now runs with breakpoints :-)

Comment: I am highlighting the attributes which were missing in my case. It is easy to overlook. After adding the debug and debuglevel in compile target, the issue was resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

the same thing happened to me and it was because I had "shrinkResources true" and "minifyEnabled true" in Gradle App

```
buildTypes {
        debug {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```